# Find walkable routes from polygons to points

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I have a dataset that contains specific census tract polygons and schools, hospitals and police stations point data.

The goal is to generate walkable distance routes from the polygons to the point data.

I am thinking of first creating walkable service areas with respect to time.

Second step is to generate walkable distance routes from the polygons to the point data. For this what steps will I need to do? Also will I use Routes under network analyst for this purpose?

PS I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1

Comment: What network dataset are you using? Ideally, you have one with a walking travel mode already setup.  If not, your first course of action would be to create this, and gather any necessary data to generate that travel mode.  If you use the network analyst tools provided by ArcGIS Online, there is a built-in [walking travel mode](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/travel-modes-analysis-mv.htm#:~:text=taken%20into%20consideration.-,Walking%20time,-Walking%20time%20finds).  Route would create the faster route between your input locations.

Comment: @evv_gis, thank you for the quick response, yes we do have streets network dataset. Thank you for providing the additional details in regard to AGOL. I will go ahead and look into both, walking travel mode in AGOL and the Routes tool in Pro to see what works best.